# simplify a regex, probably easy

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I tried to simplify a simple regex on nginx but it doesn't work,

here is what I have first:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/q-(.*)/$   /index.php?cat=$1&q=$2  last;

rewrite ^/(.*)/$   /index.php?cat=$1  last;
```

Parameter `q` is optional, I would like to write a single regex,

I tried :

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/(q-(.*)\/)?$   /index.php?cat=$1&q=$2   last;
```

It's probably something stupid but it doesn't work, any idea?

Comment: It will actually be more complex if you try to merge them. Namely because in the first case you use the match of two groups and in the second - just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> rewrite ^/(.*)/(q-(.*)/)?$   /index.php?cat=$1&q=$2   last;

You would need to use a pattern like the following:

```
^/([^/]*)/(q-(.*)/)?$
```

And now the value of the `q` parameter is in `$3`, not `$2` (because of the additional parenthesised subpattern.

The first part of the pattern also needs to be made *non-greedy*, since the last part of the pattern is now optional. By default `.*` will be *greedy* and consume the entire string. It can be made non-greedy by either specifying `.*?` or use a negated character class `[^/]*` (as I have done). The `*` should probably be changed to `+` unless you really can have empty parameters.

But @ndn has a valid point, it might now be one directive rather than two, but is it *simplified*? Not really.